# What happens if a Android Service is started multiple times?

Tags: android

If I have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DownloadService.class);     
for(int i=0;i<filesArray.length;i++){        
     startService(intent);          
}
```

In this code `DownloadService` extends `IntentService`.

So now when I'm calling `startService(intent)` does that mean that I'm starting a new service every time `startService(intent)` is called or does that mean that `DownloadService` is run once and then each time I call `startService(intent)` it will just pass a different intent with a different startId.

Does this make sense, and which one of these is the case ?

Comment: almost in every interview this question will ask :)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The Service will only run in one instance. However, everytime you start the service, the `onStartCommand()` method is called.

This is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService)

Comment: Thanks. It also says there: "The startService() method returns immediately and the Android system calls the service's onStartCommand() method. If the service is not already running, the system first calls onCreate(), then calls onStartCommand()." So if the service is already running then the system will skip the onCreate() method and call onStartCommand() only or what ?

Comment: I don't really know, but I am pretty sure that is the case (makes a lot of sence not to call `onCreate()` if the service is already created). It should be easy to determine if you put a `Log.i()` in both of the callbacks and check the LogCat.

Comment: Just did that... and strangely enough it starts the onCreate after the last startService() call!!!

Comment: That is because `startService()` is asynchronous. So while you are looping the calls, the service itself hasn't gotten any resources and didn't start yet.

Comment: that doesn't make sense, asynchronous and as a sevice it should start in separate thread right away

Comment: @neelabh not "right away", it takes some time to start the service, and the "for" loop would be still running and calling again and again the service, so the first tries wouldn't find any service running yet... so the method startService() would be called a couple of times, until service startup is complete. Please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 29):

Absolutely Correct.
Only one instance of Service is created for an application process.
And when you call `StartService();` again, then only `onStartCommand()` gets called and new Intent is passed to `onStartCommand()` method.

**Note:** `onCreate()` is not called again.

**About calling `bindService()` multiple times:**

When you call `bindService()` multiple times, then again only one instance is used for Service and Android Runtime returns same IBinder object to client.

Means, `onBind()` is not called multiple times. And just cached IBinder object is returned.

Comment: Does `onStop()` have to be called for every corresponding `onStartCommand`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky : First of all,There is no such callback method onStop() in Service. We need to call stopService() or stopSelf() to stop a service. And when the onStartCommand() has been called multiple times for multiple intents, then we need to call just stopSelf() or stopService() only once.   If using IntentService, you should call stopSelfResult(int id)  passing start id of request  from onHandleIntent(), which will stop corresponding start id request, that was placed in work queue of IntentService.   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Adding some more information to the above answers which may be helpful for others is that, `startId` that the `onStartCommand()` method receives is different for every `startService()` call.

Also if we write in for loop as mentioned above, code written in `onHandleIntent()` would execute so many times as defined by the for loop frequency, but in sequence and not in parallel.

The concept is `IntentService` creates a work queue and each request to `startService()` trigger `onStartCommand()` which in turn stores the intent in work queue and then pass the intent one by one to `onHandleIntent()`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService):

> The startService() method returns immediately, and the Android system calls the service's onStartCommand() method. If the service isn't already running, the system first calls onCreate(), and then it calls onStartCommand().

and

> Multiple requests to start the service result in multiple corresponding calls to the service's onStartCommand(). However, only one request to stop the service (with stopSelf() or stopService()) is required to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful comments from [Android official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Stopping):

(highlighted by me)

> If your service handles **multiple** requests to `onStartCommand()` concurrently, you **shouldn't stop** the service when you're done processing a start request, **as you might have received a new start request (stopping at the end of the first request would terminate the second one)**. To avoid this problem, you can use `stopSelf(int)` to ensure that your request to stop the service is always based on the most recent start request. That is, when you call `stopSelf(int)`, you **pass the ID** of the start request (the **startId** delivered to `onStartCommand()`) to which your stop request corresponds. Then, if the service receives a new start request before you are able to call stopSelf(int), the **ID doesn't match and the service doesn't stop.**