# how to prevent service to run again if already running android

Tags: android, service, android-service

On click of a button I want to start service using method `startService(new Intent(currentActivity.this,MyService.class))` but if service is running I don't want to call  this method to avoid run service that is already running.How this is possible.I am using both **Intent service** and **Service** in same project and want to apply same condition for both.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/starting-a-service-multiple-times

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A service will only run once, so you can call `startService(Intent)` multiple times.

You will receive an `onStartCommand()` in the service. So keep that in mind.

Source:
Note that multiple calls to `Context.startService()` do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to `onStartCommand()`), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once `Context.stopService()` or `stopSelf()` is called; however, services can use their `stopSelf(int)` method to ensure the service is not stopped until started intents have been processed.

At: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html on topic: Service Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Your comment will help me a lot but don't want to call these methods again if service is running.any other idea???

Comment: @AtulBhardwaj: Calls to `startService()` *always* trigger `onStartComand()`. Period. So, either do not call `startService()`, or have a smarter `onStartCommand()` that can deal with being called multiple times.

Answer (score 30):

Use `startService()`.
Start Service will call `onStartCommand()` If the Service isn't started yet it will Call `onCreate()`. Initialize your variables and/or start a Thread in `onCreate()`.

Comment: this is the right answer. onCreate() is overlooked.

Comment: that means how many times we want to start the service onCreate invoke only once ?

Comment: @NoorHossain Correct.

Answer (score 7):

Bind your service; when starting call:

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this,ServiceTask.class);
    startService(bindIntent);
    bindService(bindIntent,mConnection,0);
```

Then to check if your service is working, use a method like:

```
    public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName){ 
             final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)Application.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);     
             final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);      
           for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {         
             if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)){             
                return true;         
             }     
           }     
         return false; 
        }
```

Comment: Does this code work in case only if I bind service to activity???I think binding service to a activity will run until app is running.Please comment

Comment: This won't work always. It does not take "Service being stopped" into account. And it is mainly for showing Running Services UI. I've used this and it won't work in KitKat always. Rather, you can use startService ALWAYS and make use of service onCreate and onStartCommand to do your tasks. It is the right way.

Comment: Why is a **Bound Service** necessary here?  Can't we just use a **Started Service**?

Comment: getRunningServices is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

Whenever we start any service from any activity , Android system calls the service's onStartCommand() method And If the service is not already running, the system first calls onCreate(), and then it calls onStartCommand().

So mean to say is that android service start's only once in its lifecycle and keep it running till stopped.if any other client want to start it again then only onStartCommand() method will invoked all the time.

Comment: is there any documentation source ?

Answer (score 0):

So, for avoiding restarting a task again and again, You can use boolean values, that the task is already started or ongoing. Put the method both in oncreate and onstartCommand, and checked with the boolean:

```
 boolean isTimerTaskRunning = false;
private boolean isServiceKeepRunning(){
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return settings.getBoolean("silentModeKeepRunning", true);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Called");
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: keepRunning "+isServiceKeepRunning());
        if(!isTimerTaskRunning) {
            startTimerTask();
            isTimerTaskRunning = true;
        }
        //startForeground(REQUEST_CODE /* ID of notification */, notificationbuilder().build());

    }

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        localData = new LocalData(this);
      //  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: Called");
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: keepRunning "+isServiceKeepRunning());

        Toast.makeText(this, "This is The Mode For Silent. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(!isTimerTaskRunning) {
            Log.i(TAG, "TimerTask was not Running - started from onStartCommand");
           startTimerTask();
           isTimerTaskRunning = true;

        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "TimerTask was already Running - checked from onStartCommand");

        }
        //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        startForeground(REQUEST_CODE /* ID of notification */, notificationbuilder().build());

        return  START_STICKY;
}
```