# How to check previously started custom own service is running or not

Tags: android, service, android-service, background-thread

Hi I have one activity and one service class
from activity am starting service 
in one point i want to start service but at same point i want to check that service is already running if yes then i dont want to call start service if not then i will strat but my problem is that how i will get to know that service is running or not?

i used below code but it not working for me is any other code which will help me out

```
  private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("TimerService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "running", 100).show();
            return true;

        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not running", 100).show();
    return false;
}
```

this code always show me not tunning even if it is running

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check whether it's running or not. Both `startService()` and `stopService()` will handle the corresponding states, so if you call `startService()` and your `Service` was already running, nothing will happen (it will just keep running). The same goes to `stopService()`.

Comment: i need to check once again cause when am calling start service 2 times it restart the countdown timer from 60 sec (60  sec is my limit of counter) i called countdown timer code in my service

Comment: Have a look at this, this will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739413/how-to-prevent-service-to-run-again-if-already-running-android

Comment: thanks 

i got conclusion from your provided link as well as i saw one more link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/starting-a-service-multiple-times


from this link i get to know that we can call service as many time no worry only thing that  the  onStartCommand() from service will be  call multiple time(i.e how many times we start the service)

and unfortunatly my timer related code was in it so am moving that code from onStartCommand() to onCreate () method 


thanks for your help