# Android: Passing variables to an already running service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

I am having issues passing a value from an Activity to an already running service. I was wondering what the best approach to take would be? Adding extras wont work as I believe this has to be done before the intent is started? (correct me if i'm wrong).

Any help would be great! I can elaborate if needed.

Dan.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If your service is not an `IntentService`, you can call `startService(...)` as many times you want. The service will run the first time but next calls will result in new `onStartCommand()` calls with the new extras you need.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/starting-a-service-multiple-times) and the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService).

Comment: Agreed, here's more proof from [`Activity#startService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)'s documentation.

Comment: Ah I see. Dont know how I missed this reading the documentation. Thanks for your swift answer!

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15899750/1340631) which explains how to to call `startService()` to pass new Intents and read them inside your service during `onStartCommand()`. Essentially the same answer as here but a little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

**pass intent extra to service
from activity start this intent**
if service is running try this from activity and pass param with putExtra.

```
Intent rc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myService.class);
rc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //important for Android 10
rc.putExtra("parama","ciao");
rc.putExtra("paramb","hello");
startService(rc);
```

Remember, new thread, exit to main Thread.

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            //start service..
        }    
}
```

**your service**

```
 public class myService extends Service {
               @Override
                public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                if (intent.hasExtra("parama")){            
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b=intent.getExtras();
                String par_a=b.getString("parama");
                }
                if (intent.hasExtra("paramb")){            
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b=intent.getExtras();
                String par_b =b.getString("paramb");
                }
        }
    }
```