# Starting service multiple times will nest calls made in onStartCommand()?

Tags: android, service

I am calling `startService()` multiple times in my class.

there is a function in my service's `onStartCommand()`, like this -

```
    Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(StaticValues.TAG, "service started.");
        processItem();
        return 0;
    }
```

My question is, if I start service again, `onStartComamnd()` will be called again. So will this call wait till my previous call is over or it will execute both calls to `processItem()` parallelly?

**Edit : Answer I found from links in comments**

> `startService()` is asynchronous. So while you are looping the calls, the service itself hasn't gotten any resources and didn't start yet.
>
> The Service will only run in one instance. However, everytime you start the service, the onStartCommand() method is called.

Check : [What happens if a Service is started multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/what-happens-if-a-service-is-started-multiple-times)

Comment: [Check](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: onStartCommand is called in the UI thread so the answer is no: no parallelly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I start a service multiple times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019899/what-happens-if-i-start-a-service-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

***A Service can only be started once, if you want to and love to complicate things use a boolean flag***

Using `startService()` overrides the default service lifetime that is managed by `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`: it requires the service to remain running until `stopService(Intent)` is called, regardless of whether any clients are connected to it. Note that calls to `startService()` are not nesting: no matter how many times you call `startService()`, a single call to `stopService(Intent)` will stop it.

> If the service is being started or is already running, the
>   ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else
>   if the service does not exist null is returned.
>
> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though
>   they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()),
>   so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped
>   once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called;

[Link to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

[Life Cycle of a Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)

Comment: But it is true that `onStartCommand()` will be called. So I can assume that `processItem()` function will be called atleast twice?

Comment: It totally depends on when the call to `Context.stopService()` is called - which will nullify all the previous calls.

Comment: Consider I never call stopService(), then?

Comment: Please go through the Service Lifecycle, it also depends on your return type. Please also consider psKink's comment that a Service runs on the UI thread. You might instead want to use an `IntentService`.

Comment: I figured it out, my function `processItem()`  will be called each time as `onStartCommand()` is also getting called.

Comment: I suggest you dont call it on the UI thread. It will cause potential problems in your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81432/discussion-between-darpan-and-skynet).