# Does start of a Service from MainActivity and fragment duplication threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-service

I start a background service from `MainActivity` and as well as from `Fragment`.

**Will it create duplicate threads? So It will be 2 services running?**

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //...
  context.startService(new Intent(context,gps_service.class));
//...
```

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {

//... Click method of the button calls
getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),gps_service.class));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019919/5154891.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it create duplicate threads? So It will be 2 services running?

**NO** only one service will be launched and only one will running

Answer (score 2):

**There will be only one service running.** .

> Will it create duplicate threads? So It will be 2 services running?

Each time you call startService() There can be two possibilities.

1. If Service in not started previously then it will start as per its life cycle . **onCreate -> onStartCammand** and so on.
2. If Service is previously started then only  **onStartCammand()** will get called with desired intent which you have passed to it .

Answer (score 1):

Only one instance is exist for each `Service`. If your service is already running then `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` will be called if you try to start again.

From [Android Official site](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise.

So by default `Service` use Main Thread and [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) use a background thread. If you want to do some long running task then use `IntentService` or create a background Thread in `Service`.

For more check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)